only homepage renders but not other pages
I have a basic fullstack app built with Node, Koa, and Preact. I'm trying to get Preact routing to work. I created a component and route for an About page. When I start the Preact dev server I can access the /about page successfully at localhost:5173/about.
The problem is that when I start my Node server I get Not Found when I try to go to localhost:8080/about. However, I can successfully render the homepage by going to /.
(root) index.js
const server = require('./server');

const port = 8080;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});

server\index.js
const Koa = require('koa');
const serve = require('koa-static');
const path = require('path');

const server = new Koa();

// Serve static files
server.use(serve(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));

module.exports = server;

client\src\pages\home\index.jsx
export function Home() {
    return (
        <h1>Preact App Homepage</h1>
    );
}

client\src\pages\about\index.jsx
export function About() {
    return (
        <h1>About Page</h1>
    );
}

client\src\index.jsx
import { LocationProvider, Router, Route, hydrate, prerender as ssr } from 'preact-iso';
import { Header } from './components/Header.jsx';
import { Home } from './pages/Home/index.jsx';
import { About } from './pages/_about.jsx';
import { NotFound } from './pages/_404.jsx';
import './style.css';

export function App() {
    return (
        <LocationProvider>
            <Header />
            <main>
                <Router>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                    <Route default component={NotFound} />
                </Router>
            </main>
        </LocationProvider>
    );
}

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
}

export async function prerender(data) {
    return await ssr(<App {...data} />);
}

client\dist\index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" >
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
        <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" >
        <title>Vite + Preact</title>
        <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-7GmgnfZn.js"></script>
        <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/index-BgxwHnNi.js">
        <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-C_LgOj56.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"><header><nav><a href="/" class="active">Home</a><a href="/404">404</a></nav></header><main><h1>Preact App Homepage</h1></main><script type="isodata"></script></div>
    </body>
</html>


Is this the "Not Found" page, or a 404? Are you prerendering the app? I.e., does /dist/about/index.html exist?

yes it is the Not Found page, and not the 404 page that comes with Preact. In dist there is no /about/index, but there is an assets folder where I can see js files being created, such as index-CIlfueN-.js. When I search that generated file, I can see the About Page text in the file. When I set up Preact I chose SSG.

Gotcha, sounds like the /about page isn't being prerendered then. Added an answer, but it'd be helpful if you could also upload your <Header /> component as that all content plays into prerendering.

It looks like you might have two separate issues:

Koa returns a 404 Not Found when accessing any page but /
You're not prerendering all the content you wish to be


The Koa issue is pretty simple: it looks for HTML files in your static output that match the provided URL, and when it cannot find anything, it falls back to a 404. However, this is essentially only a problem as you're missing HTML content. You may want to configure Koa to instead route all traffic to say /404 when HTML cannot be found, or perhaps /, but it's very subjective. Koa provides it's own Not Found response by default which you may want to think about overriding, but it's not the main problem here.
As for prerendering, the Preact prerenderer in @preact/preset-vite (full disclosure: I wrote it) will crawl your app looking for links to prerender. Essentially, it'll render /, read the resulting HTML, and extract links within (<a href="/about">About Us</a> -> /about) to continue to prerender with, stopping once all pages have been prerendered and no more links have been found. This however can be an issue if you haven't actually linked to a route you want prerendered; typically you'd see this with error pages more than anything, as you're probably not going to link to (say) /404 or /500, but you might want them prerendered all the same.
In the default prerender template we add links to the header (which you haven't uploaded here) to cover this case, but I'd guess you've removed them, hence why the /about page isn't prerendered.
To fix this, you have two options:

Ensure all the pages you want prerendered have discoverable links
Use the additionalPrerenderRoutes plugin option to explicitly add pages

// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    preact({
      prerender: {
        enabled: true,
        // ...
        additionalPrerenderRoutes: ['/about', '/error-page', '...']
      }
    })
  ]
});

Prerender config docs

I tried both of those options, for Preact, and they both work. Thanks! I ended up not needing to touch my backend to fix this. Also, maybe the Preact docs can have a note about needing a link or update to the vite config, in order to ensure all pages get prerendered.
